# Writing to a JSON file (Using Node.js to work on a Localhost server)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

So I am using C3.js, a chart library built on top of the widely used D3.js visualization library. So as a part of the webpage that I am creating with a chart, I want to include a user interaction in which the user can input values for a new object that can be charted along with current objects that are already charted via a form on the html page. I'm using JSON data as the file format that's being read into the chart. I want to know how I can write to/update this file from the javascript code so that the data now includes the new object. As I am a novice with web-based technologies I'm not too sure as to how data gets updated on servers. The server is a localhost created by a file, app.js, which creates a node server.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen('14000');
```

I included the above code for my app.js as a reference if that makes any difference.
The file format for the json file is as shown below...

```
[
      {name: "Lane Warner",age: 27,height: 231,weight: 120},
      {name: "Hickman Bishop",age: 29,height: 125,weight: 180},
      {name: "Tracy Sheppard",age: 30,height: 200,weight: 155},
      {name: "Madeleine Spence",age: 30,height: 179,weight: 112},
      {name: "Alicia Beasley",age: 36,height: 300,weight: 200},
      {name: "Bryant Fitzpatrick",age: 23,height: 321,weight: 250},
      {name: "Stevenson Mcdonald",age: 30,height: 155,weight: 199},
      {name: "Hannah Ratliff",age: 21,height: 189,weight: 136},
      {name: "Alexandra Williamson",age: 39,height: 258,weight: 123}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [fs.readFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) module to read from a file, and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse the JSON.

json-util.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports.loadJson = function (file, callback) {
  fs.readFile('file.json', { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err); // file reading error
    try {
      // parse and return json to callback
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      callback(null, json);
    } catch (ex) {
      // catch JSON parsing errors so your app doesn't crash
      callback(ex);
    }
  });
};
```

If you want to read the json file synchronously, you can also use `json = require('file.json')`. Note that `require()` is relative to the current file, and `fs.readFile()` is relative to the cwd.

Conversely, you can re-write the JSON to the file using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [fs.writeFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback):

```
module.exports.writeJson = function (file, json, callback) {
  fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(json), callback);
};
```

Also keep in mind any concurrency issues such as where two requests try to modify the same file at the same time. A timeline like this would be bad:

1. Request A reads the JSON.
2. Request B reads the JSON.
3. Request A adds an item to the array and re-writes the JSON.
4. Request B adds an item to the array and re-writes the JSON.

In this case, the addition request A made will be completely erased by request B. To avoid this, it would be best to always only have one copy of the JSON in memory, and re-write it every time you modify it. I think this is beyond the scope of your question, but wanted to point it out.

If you didn't care about concurrency, you could have an app like this:

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

// if you're using Express 4.x, bodyParser is no longer built-in
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// here we import the file which has our loadJson and writeJson functions
var jsonUtil = require('./json-util.js');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/additem/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  // turn ID into a file name, and be careful not to expose security holes
  var filename = idToFileName(req.params.id);
  jsonUtil.loadJson(filename, function (err, json) {

    // TODO: make sure you handle errors
    // if err is not null, you can either consider it an error, or
    // you could simply say json = [] and start a new file

    // should also do validation checks like if(json instanceof Array) and
    // verify that req.body exists and is properly formatted, etc

    json.push(req.body); // push the object from the request body into the array

    // re-save the file
    jsonUtil.writeJson(filename, json, function (err) {
      if (err) next(err);
      else res.send(200);
    });
  });
});

server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen('14000');
```

Then, a request which looks something like:

```
POST /additem/1
Content-Type: application/json

{ "name": "Alexandra Williamson", "age": 39, "height": 258, "weight": 123 }
```

Will append to an array in which ever json file `id = 1` maps to.

Comment: So I understand what you did with the app.js code and the use of the modules. The request that you put at the bottom of the response is where I have the question. Can that request be put in the html script portion?

Comment: @user3775273 it's just an HTTP POST request to `/additem/1` with a `Content-Type` header set to `application/json` and a request body which is json. It would probably be easiest to send as an ajax request.

Comment: I'm a novice with web-related technologies but isn't the reason I'm using node because I don't want to have to use ajax requests? I have an array of paths to local json files and I just want to add to the current one. I need to know how to get the data in the form I made to be seen by the server and to be appended to the end of the array of the json file. I'm completely lost as to how to do this though. I read about using the action and method attributes for the form. Could you provide any feedback on this? Thank you for your assistance thus far.

Comment: Node.js is just a backend language, and has nothing to do with the decision to use ajax or not. If your question is about how parse data sent using a form with node.js, then that's a separate question. There's lots of information. For instance, you might start with the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware or a google search. If you still end up lost, just ask another question on Stack Overflow.